# Issues aligning UIButton in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to align a UIButton within my ViewController. I can't tell what the specific name is of my UIButton so I think that's why I'm having a hard time moving it as a subview. Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
[self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

//Modify to fit screen

CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.333333, 1.333333);
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(180));
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, rotate);
self.vImagePreview.transform = transform;

[self.vImagePreview sendSubviewToFront:UIButton];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];

_stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
[session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];



[session startRunning];
}

-(IBAction)captureNow {
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in _stillImageOutput.connections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection)
    {
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", _stillImageOutput);
[_stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
     if (exifAttachments)
     {
         // Do something with the attachments.
         NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"no attachments");
     }

     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

     self.vImage.image = image;

     //Saved Photo modifications go here

     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
 }];
}
@end
```

and my headers, just in case:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h>

#define DEGREES_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *vImagePreview;
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *vImage;

@end
```

Some clarification:

My button is on my storyboard. The button should trigger the CaptureNow method, taking a picture. I just can't figure out how to get it to appear over the preview layer.

Comment: Please be clear with question. You are posted question "Issues aligning UIButton in UIView" and the code you are posted is used for taking picture using AVCaptureSession. I didn't find any UIButton io your code.

Comment: Give some detail where it is and for what purpose it is. So that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, my button is on my storyboard. The button should trigger the CaptureNow method, taking a picture. I just can't figure out how to get it to appear over the preview layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your UIbutton is on storyboard, so instead of using

```
[self.vImagePreview sendSubviewToFront:UIButton];
```

**use this line to display UIBUtton on top**.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:UIButton];
```

**Just before start session running at the end of the emethod.**